# cron selinux security context issue

Tags: cron, redhat, fedora, selinux

my system is fedora 23.

trying to run a cronjob that is blocked by selinux in /etc/crontab.

```
* * * * sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat root DISPLAY=:0 eog $HOME/Pictures/somepic.jpg
```

context for crontab:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 2664 Jan 23 18:12 /etc/crontab
```

if i run selinux in permissive mode, the job runs every time.

here's the journal entry for crond in 'enforce mode':

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2016-01-20 10:40:21 PST. --
Jan 23 18:25:01 localhost.localdomain CROND[20342]: (root) CMDOUT (/bin/sh: root: command not found)
Jan 23 18:25:25 localhost.localdomain crond[938]: (CRON) INFO (Shutting down)
Jan 23 18:25:25 localhost.localdomain crond[18645]: (CRON) INFO (Syslog will be used instead of sendmail.)
Jan 23 18:25:25 localhost.localdomain crond[18645]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 12% if used.)
Jan 23 18:25:25 localhost.localdomain crond[18645]: ((null)) Unauthorized SELinux context=system_u:system_r:system_cronjob_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 file_context=unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 (/etc/crontab)
Jan 23 18:25:25 localhost.localdomain crond[18645]: (root) FAILED (loading cron table)
Jan 23 18:25:25 localhost.localdomain crond[18645]: (root) Unauthorized SELinux context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 file_context=unconfined_u:object_r:user_cron_spool_t:s0 (/var/spool/cron/root)
Jan 23 18:25:25 localhost.localdomain crond[18645]: (root) FAILED (loading cron table)
Jan 23 18:25:25 localhost.localdomain crond[18645]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Jan 23 18:25:25 localhost.localdomain crond[18645]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)
```

sebool settings:

```
cron_can_relabel --> off
cron_system_cronjob_use_shares --> off
cron_userdomain_transition --> on
fcron_crond --> off
```

Comment: @Jakuje the `sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat` is valid syntax for the day-of-week field. It may not work with some cron daemons on some distros but to my knowledge it works with most of the ones I've used. I've seen it capitalized and not so I suspect it is not case-sensitive but again I don't know if this depends on the choice of daemon or not.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue.  Had a crontab that worked great for a long time.  Made an edit with crontab -e, and it stopped working.  Tried as both root and normal user.  Some searching around, this is a currently known bug.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1263328

I tried the workaround listed in comment #19.  It's working fine.

Create file `mycron.cil` with content:

```
(allow unconfined_t user_cron_spool_t( file ( entrypoint)))
```

Then run:
`semodule -i mycron.cil`

Then restart cron:
`systemctl restart crond.service`

Comment 21 tells how to remove the workaround when a fix is issued.

Remove by running:
`semodule -r mycron`

and I assume restart cron again.

Comment: Note that this bug should be fixed as of January 26, 2016 (one day after your answer). If you're finding a similar problem in up-to-date Fedora after that, it's almost certainly a different bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the type of the cron file under var/spool/cron

Try this to apply files triggerd 'Unauthorized SELinux context' messages

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t user_cron_spool_t "/var/spool/cron(/.*)?"
# restorecon -R -vv /var/spool/cron
```

Answer (score -1):

I was trying this for shutting down my rhel 7.3 server automatically at 11:00 pm daily through cron job in /etc/crontab.
I faced the similar issue and selinux did not allowed to run the job.

However I got the solution by creating a new crontab file in /etc/cron.d/ and the cron job successfully executed and shutdown the system on defined time in /etc/cron.d/crontab file.

I got solution from below RHEL page on point 24.1.2 Scheduling a Cron Job""

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-automating_system_tasks

Comment: There is nothing that explains how to handle selinux problems and I dont see how the cronjob above is different from the one in these docs. 

Could you please elaborate why you propose this as a solution to the problem described here?